# How to display toast inside timer?

Tags: android, toast

I want to display toast message inside timer and I used the following code :

```
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate( new TimerTask()
{       
public void run()
{
    try {  
        fun1();
        } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace(); }            
    }   
}, 0,60000);    

public void fun1()
{
    //want to display toast
}
```

And I am getting following error:

> WARN/System.err(593): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
>
> WARN/System.err(593):     at android.os.Handler.(Handler.java:121)
>
> WARN/System.err(593):     at android.widget.Toast.(Toast.java:68)
>
> WARN/System.err(593):     at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:231)

Thanks.

Comment: I have put together all these information in a full working code , see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11906361/how-to-display-a-toast-in-a-timer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't make UI updates inside separate Thread, like Timer. You should use Handler object for UI update:

```
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate( new TimerTask() {
private Handler updateUI = new Handler(){
@Override
public void dispatchMessage(Message msg) {
    super.dispatchMessage(msg);
    fun1();
}
};
public void run() { 
try {
updateUI.sendEmptyMessage(0);
} catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace(); }
}
}, 0,60000);
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way (IMO) is:

```
new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        final String message = "Hi";
        MyActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

The key being MyActivity.this.runOnUiThread(Runnable).

Answer (score 0):

You have to call UIThread for showing Toast, not from timer thread.

Else call UI thread from that timer thread.

This link will help you,

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html

and this

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/commontasks.html#threading

Answer (score 0):

create a `Handler` and display toast in this

```
private Handler handler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
            // Toast here
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You need access to the Context of the application to be able to do this. Try creating your own class which takes the context as input parameter:

```
private class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {
    private Context context;
    public MyTimerTask(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Toast text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Then in your timer:

```
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate( new MyTimerTask(this), 0,60000);
```

Comment: This didn't work for me! It still gave the same error:
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to make my own toast with my own views.

I've successfully combined your approaches. The following code allows me to show toasts and change/remove views without crashing, just change the parameters of the `MyTimerTask` constructor to whatever you need to work on.

```
public void yourFunction(){

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    MyTimerTask mtc = new MyTimerTask(this.getContext(), tvNotice);
    timer.schedule(mtc, 1000);
}

private class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {

    private TextView tv;
    private Context context;
    public MyTimerTask(Context pContext, TextView pTv) {
        this.tv = pTv;
        this.context = pContext;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        updateUI.sendEmptyMessage(0);
    }

    private Handler updateUI = new Handler(){
        @Override
        public void dispatchMessage(Message msg) {
            super.dispatchMessage(msg);


            tv.setText("TextView Message");
            Toast.makeText(context, "Toast Message", 0).show();
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to make a simple project that could display a Toast in a Timer.
The Timer would be started using a service. Then, the Timer starts when the service is started and stops when service is stopped.

Class 1

```
package com.example.connect;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button button1,button2;
 private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);


}


public void Start(View v)
{
    startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this , Connect_service.class));

}

public void Stop(View v)
{
    stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this , Connect_service.class));

}

}
```

Class 2

```
package com.example.connect;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Connect_service extends Service{

Timer timer = new Timer();
TimerTask updateProfile = new CustomTimerTask(Connect_service.this);

public void onCreate() {

    super.onCreate();

    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(updateProfile, 0, 5000);

}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    timer.cancel();
}



@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

}
```

Class 3

```
package com.example.connect;

import java.util.TimerTask;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class CustomTimerTask extends TimerTask {


private Context context;
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

public CustomTimerTask(Context con) {
    this.context = con;
}



@Override
public void run() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                   Toast.makeText(context, "In Timer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
        }
    }).start();

}

}
```