# Android Service...application crashes when making a Toast

Tags: android, service, crash

This is my Service class:

```
public class MySrv extends Service {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();
    final Context c = getApplicationContext();
    Timer t = new Timer("mytimer");
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(c, "Not a beautyfull day today...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };
    t.schedule(task, 5000, 6000);
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
    }
```

}

The application crashes at Toast.makeText()... So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please post your logcat output (logcat view in Eclipse or `adb logcat` in a shell)

Comment: Are you sure it is crashing at Toast.makeText()? Did you try to debug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are trying to update the UI in the timers thread, you should use a Handler for this.

Read [How to display toast inside timer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218801/how-to-display-toast-inside-timer)

Answer (score 3):

The `TimerTask`'s `run()` method doesn't execute in the UI thread, so you can't do UI-related things like creating a `Toast`.

Investigate using a `Handler` or `runOnUiThread()` instead.

Example:

```
    final Handler handler = new Handler ();
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        handler.post (new Runnable (){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(c, "Not a beautyfull day today...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
         });
    }
```

Comment: Also look this link: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make a Toast in another Thread, you can use a Handler to do it or use the runOnUiThread.

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {
private Handler toastTeller;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstance);
        toastTeller = new Handler() {
           public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
             if (msg.what == 2)
                Toast.makeText(LibraryActivity.this, msg.obj.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           super.handleMessage(msg);
           }
         };
     new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
        Message msg = new Message();
        msg.what = 2;
        msg.obj = "Your item was downloaded.";
        toastTeller.sendMessage(msg);
        }
 }).start();
}
```