# WakefulIntentService and Toast

Tags: android, toast, commonsware-cwac

I guess this is a question straight to Mark, but I can't for the life of me get a Toast notification to work from inside the doWakefulWork method of WakefulIntentService.  It works from the onCreate, but I need to use some data I am getting through the intent within the toast message.

I've tried to instantiate the handler from within the OnCreate but this doesn't seem to do anything.  I've tried everything I can think of.  The Toast just doesn't seem to run on the main thread.  Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, `WakefulIntentService` is not designed for scenarios where a `Toast` would make any sense, since the user may or may not be around. Moreover, services should not be directly affecting the UI this way, since if the user *is* around the user may not appreciate your `Toast` in the middle of their game, their navigation, their movie, etc. I would rather you use something else (e.g., ordered broadcast to update a foreground activity or display a `Notification` if there is no such activity).

If you are really certain that you want to use a `Toast` from a service, your problem should have nothing to do with `WakefulIntentService` -- you would have the same problems with a regular `IntentService`. [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5651839/android-service-application-crashes-when-making-a-toast) has some answers demonstrating the use of a `Toast` from a service's background thread using a `Handler`, which may help indicate where your `Handler` implementation is going wrong.

Comment: The Toast notification is actually a user preference setting, so the user has to ask for it in order for it to be shown.  I have found a solution in the thread you linked to (from Marcos).

Answer (score 0):

```
       private boolean showToast = false;
        ...
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (showToast) {
             Toast.makeText(this,"YourText",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             showToast = false;
        }
        }
```

Just set `showToast = true;` from anywhere to showing you toast notification.

Comment: Thanks, but I need the text of the toast to be dynamic.  I won't know what to put there until I receive the intent