# Android: alert box after 3000 ms

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

In my program I want this alert dialog to show after 3000ms. how can I do this? I tried a lot but I couldnt. any Idea?

Help is always appreciated...!

```
     AlertDialog.Builder successfullyLogin = new Builder(Register.this);
   successfullyLogin.setCancelable(false);
  successfullyLogin.setMessage("Successfully Login !");
//  successfullyLogin.wait(3000);// this line is nt working
  successfullyLogin.setPositiveButton("Ok",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
  {
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) 
   {


   }
   });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the wait function you are calling should be specifically used for multithreading...

try this...

```
   new Thread()
   {
       public void run()
       {
            sleep(3000);
           AlertDialog.Builder successfullyLogin = new Builder(LWM.this);
            successfullyLogin.setCancelable(false);
           successfullyLogin.setMessage("Successfully Login !").show();
           }
   };
```

Answer (score 2):

The wait method is part of java.lang.Object and causes the calling thread to wait until another thread calls the notify() or notifyAll() method of this object or until the specified timeout expires. It's not used to implement "sleep" like functionality.

You could start an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) (that will start a background thread). In the doBackGround, you could sleep the thread for 3 seconds (not blocking the UI), and in your doPostExecute you can pop the dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of showing an alert box why dont u put an suucess message as a toast for 3 seconds....
 or else if u want to show the alert box for 3 seconds first remove the ok button then use handlers for close the alert box...

Comment: ,Hmmmm Thanks,but thats not exactly what I want. I am showing a progress dialog for 3000ms and after that I should show this alert dialog(Successfully Login !).

Answer (score 1):

You could use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or [Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) to accomplish that. If you use **AsyncTask**, sleep in the background and show the dialog in `onPostExecute`

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer here should give you a good head start.  Just substitute toast for dialog and you're done.

[How to display toast inside timer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218801/how-to-display-toast-inside-timer)

i.e. Use a timer to create a new thread to count down your 3 seconds, and use a handler to display your dialog or toast message on the main UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `Handler` in your Activity's class (can be assigned local variable).  Then set it up to send a `sendEmptyMessageDelayed()` in`OnStart()`.  Then, in your handler, create the `alert dialog`.  
**Note that**, since an Activity can be terminated at any time by Android, you need to also override `OnStop()`in your Activity and call `removeMessages()` on your handler.  
If you don't do this, the message is left in the queue but your `Activitiy` will have already been terminated when the event fires.  The result is a rather confusing `Exception`.

This approach also has the benefit of being able to terminate the message from firing in the first place.  For instance, if you finish doing whatever needs to be done before then, you can simply remove the `message from the queue` and it won't fire.