# how to toast inside timerTask run.Exception is uncaught handler

Tags: android

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            time=Long.parseLong(intent.getStringExtra("time"));
    Toast.makeText(this, ""+time, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    timer=new Timer();
    TimerTask timerTask=new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            if(minute==time) {

                Log.d("AlarmService", "timer");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"ringing",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }
        }
    };
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 0, 1000*2);

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

Comment: Post your LogCat outputs

Comment: this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218801/how-to-display-toast-inside-timer

Answer (score 0):

> how to toast inside timerTask run.Exception is uncaught handler

Because showing Toast from run method of `TimerTask` which execute on  non-ui Thread.

So to fix issue use `Handler` or `runOnUiThread` to show Toast from `run` method

Answer (score 0):

You have not used

```
.show();
```

in your toast.

This should be

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"ringing",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Instead of

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"ringing",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
```